# Move the fluidRow style from the ui.R to the www/styles.css

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have 5 buttons that I would like to control all at once using css rather than having to call #button1, #button2, #button3...

Is there anyway to define like a "main" class that all the buttons will be dependent on when I make changes in the css file.

Alternatively, how would I do if I only want to control the buttons of fluidrow1 OR fluidrow2 in one go?

See my code below:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "shiny.css",
              tags$head(
                tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "shiny.css")
              ),

  fluidRow(class = "fluidrow1",
           column(6, actionButton(inputId = "button1", label = "Button 1")),
           column(6, actionButton(inputId = "button2", label = "Button 2"))
           ),
  fluidRow(id = "fluidrow2",
           column(6, actionButton(inputId = "button3", label = "Button 3")),
           column(6, actionButton(inputId = "button4", label = "Button 4"))
           ),
  actionButton(inputId = "button5", label = "Button 5")

  )
)
```

shiny.css (located in the "www" folder, only controlling button1 now)

```
#button1 {
  background-color:#07364E;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size:12pt;
  text-align: center;
  width:90px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give your buttons a class of their own with the `...` argument:

```r
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "shiny.css",
              tags$head(
                tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "shiny.css")
              ),

  fluidRow(id = "fluidrow1",
           column(6, actionButton(inputId = "button1", label = "Button 1", class = "mybuttons")),
           column(6, actionButton(inputId = "button2", label = "Button 2", class = "mybuttons"))
           ),
  fluidRow(id = "fluidrow2",
           column(6, actionButton(inputId = "button3", label = "Button 3", class = "mybuttons")),
           column(6, actionButton(inputId = "button4", label = "Button 4", class = "mybuttons"))
           ),
  actionButton(inputId = "button5", label = "Button 5", class = "mybuttons")

  )
)
```

Then you would access them in css like this:

```css
.mybuttons {
  background-color:#07364E;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size:12pt;
  text-align: center;
  width:90px
}
```

To access the ones only in fluidrow1, I would first change your argument for the first `fluidRow()` from `class = "fluidrow1"` to `id = "fluidrow1"` as I have done above. Then you would access them with:

```css
#fluidrow1 .mybuttons {
  background-color:#07364E;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size:12pt;
  text-align: center;
  width:90px
}
```

If you want to style all buttons of any kind in the UI you could also use the built-in classes for buttons:

```r
> actionButton(inputId = "test",label = "Test Label")
<button id="test" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button">Test Label</button>
```

Based on the output above you can see that `btn`, `btn-default`, and `action-button` are all classes that come with each call to `actionButton()`. You could also modify these (I have chosen `action-button` as an example):

```css
.action-button {
  background-color:#07364E;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size:12pt;
  text-align: center;
  width:90px
}
```

Though I would be careful with this, as you don't know where else this class might appear without your knowledge, versus the use of your own class which you are completely controlling (`.mybuttons` in the example above).